# kotlin/android: set each button in recyclerview to start its own activity

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I want to make an activity for selecting which level to play in a game. For that I created a recyclerview with buttons. Each of those buttons should start its corresponding level. With the code below (taken from the Adapter), they all just point to MainActivity. Is there an easy way to change this?

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.levelButton?.text = items.get(position)
        holder.itemView.levelButton.setOnClickListener{
            var gotoLevel= Intent(context,MainActivity::class.java)
            context.startActivity(gotoLevel)
    }
}
```

My apologies if this is something too obvious I´m asking. I started coding just a couple of days ago and still am in that phase where you don´t even know the appropriate google search terms for your problems.

Answer (score 2):

You should get the context from the superclass (***RecyclerView.Adapter***). And use it to create an Intent from ***setOnClickListener*** method of your ***View***

```
class YourHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    private var buttonView = view.buttonView
    // Variable for the Context
    private lateinit var context : Context
    fun bindHolder(itemData: ItemData) {
        // Init context
        context = super.itemView.context
        // OnClick Button Handler
        buttonView .setOnClickListener{
            // Move to AnotherActivity
            val intent = Intent(this.context, AnotherActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("key", ItemData.value)
            startActivity(this.context, intent, null)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have different options to achieve that - ideally, we've got our logic decoupled from the adapter and your activity should deal with the actions to process after the user clicks on one of the rows.

As far as I can tell you've defined a *ViewHolder* that should reference your views - right? You can add an item click interface like so:

```
class ViewHolder(view : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    val levelButton : TextView = view.tv_levelButton

    interface OnUserAction {

        fun onItemClick(item : Item)
    }
}
```

and in order to trigger it every time the user clicks on a cell - instead of setting it on every view update you should instead do it only once on *onCreateViewHolder*:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val holder = ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, parent, false))

    holder.onClick {
        position, _ -> action.onItemClick(items.get(position))
    }

    return holder
}
```

This *action* field that you see above, it's the interface sent on the adapter constructor:

```
class ItemsAdapter(val items: List<Item>, private val action: ViewHolder.OnUserAction)...
```

With this, in order to call a specific action, on your activity/ fragment you just need to implement the interface created - *OnUserAction*:

```
override fun onItemClick(item: Item) {
    var gotoLevel = getLevel(item)
    context.startActivity(gotoLevel)
}
```

**Edit:**
To make things easier, I've created a OnClick extension function:

```
fun <T : RecyclerView.ViewHolder> T.onClick(event: (position: Int, type: Int) -> Unit): T {
itemView.setOnClickListener {
    event.invoke(adapterPosition, itemViewType)
}
return this
```

}

Comment: Many thanks for your input. I´m trying to wrap my head around some things here: first, the space in `view.tv_ levelButton` is a typo, I assume? Second, in `holder.onClick`, I get an "unresolved reference" for the `onClick`. Any Idea why? And lastly, everywhere you have put `List<Item>`, I previously had put `ArrayList<Array>`. So I thought if I replace `Array` with `Item` everywhere, it should work. Instead I get "unresolved reference" for every occurrence of `Item`. I guess I need to declare it somewhere. Any pointers as to how and where?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. onClick is an extension function that I've created - that's why you've got that unresolved reference (I've edited my previous comment with that information). Item is a generic object that've created to show you the data that your adapter has - it should be the same type that you set your list with.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to update your data model to include the class of the activity you want to launch. Right now it looks like you just have a list of Strings. So change that to a custom object that has a string and the class you want to launch.

```
class Item(val levelButtonText: String, val activityClass: Class<*>)
```

Then your binding replaces the hardcoded MainActivity::class.java with the current item class:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = items.get(position)
    holder.levelButton?.text = item.levelButtonText
    holder.itemView.levelButton.setOnClickListener{
        var gotoLevel= Intent(context, item.activityClass)
        context.startActivity(gotoLevel)
}
```

Then, wherever you're creating your list of items for the adapter, you replace the one string with an `Item` that sets the class of the Activity you want to launch.

Hope that helps!